# Pandas to_datetime Slowing Script

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that reads a CSV file and it seems to have slowed down recently (I am sure it used to run faster with this very code). I have narrowed the issue down to this line of code:

```
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime'])
```

The CSV is quite basic:

```
2021-11-03 09:30:00-04:00,150.39,150.8,150.3,150.47,9583
```

Yet to run just 2000 rows is taking ~0.2 seconds which seems much slower than I would have thought.

I have tried updating python and pandas in case it was that but the issue is still there.

Is this amount of time normal and is there anything else I can check or do to improve the speed?

EDIT2 - I had recreated the CSV and this I thought had cured it. Unfortunately it has not and I am still at ~0.2s for this line of code to run - maybe it is the CSV file but it looks totally normal in notepad?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['datetime'])
```

**EDIT**

if it doesn't work for date format, try this:

```
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['datetime'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Comment: I ran a test on my machine, the results for 2000 lines follow:

timeReadCSV:  0:00:00.012791
timetodatetime:  0:00:00.026344

Comment: Hi - thanks for taking the time to help. Your first solution does work but it is still at 0.2s - the second does not work as it give an error of ValueError: unconverted data remains: -04:00 which I guess is the timezone. - I tried to add the timezone then I get ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True

Comment: I guess from your tests that something else it going wrong to slow it down as your results are in line with my expectation. But it is this line with the issue so what else could it be?

Comment: Actually I just deleted the CSV files and recreated them and the time has reduced and all your methods work. Thank you very much

Comment: Actually I think this just emptied the full amount of data so I am still with the same issue